Is there any sensor inside a LOX tank of a rocket for LOX level sensing?
Can anyone advise is there any sensor used for sensing the LOX level and temperatures during filling of the tank?

Very closely related but perhaps not a duplicate: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30632/6944

The Space Shuttle's LO2 tank (located in the External Tank) did have those sensors. The upper level sensors were mounted on the "lance" or "mast" near the pointed end of the tank. The lower ones were mounted near the tank outlet.

Graphic is from the External Tank System Definition Handbook
This image shows how the LO2 tank made up the nose of the External Tank.

Image source

The famous "Yikes!" – "You bet!" – "Concur!" – "We don't need any more of these!" exchange was triggered by a LOX sensor as well, in some sense, although of course not during filling but during flight.

The Saturn V stages (at least 1st stage (S-IC), 2nd stage (S-II) and 3rd stage (S-IVB)) did have LOX level sensors.
They had a capacitance-type sensor for the level, and additionally point level sensors for "full", "almost full" (slow down the fill process), "almost empty", and "empty". (I read about it in "NASA Saturn-V Owners' Workshop Manual" by Woods W. David.)
The TECHNICAL INFORMATION SUMMARY
APOLLO-10 (AS-505) document contains some informations, and various other documents as well. The level sensors were also call "fuel mass probes" or "capacitance probes":

The Lox tank is located in the lower end of the propellant structure and is surrounded by the aft skirt assembly. The Lox tank is equipped internally with a slosh baffle, a chilldowll pump, a 13.5 foot propellant utilization probe, temperature and level sensors, and fill, pressurization and ventpipes.

The Saturn V Flight Manual SA-503 contains a lot more informations. Here are some for the S-II stage with nice drawings:

Continuous capacitance probes and point level sensors in the LH2 and lox tanks monitor propellant mass. mass. During the propellant loading sequence, the point level ensors are used to indicate to GSE the level of propellants in he tanks. In flight, the level sensors provide signals to the LVDC in order to accomplish a smooth engine cutoff at propellant depletion. The capacitance probes provide outputs used to operate the propellant utilization (PU) control valve.



Figure 6-22 shows the S-IVB stage, mentioning the probes and sensors. Figure 4-11 shows the S-IC stage's fuel tank including probe/sensors, but not for the LOX tank.

Here's a document that shows the level sensors "capacitance type mass sensor"  for the 3rd stage on pdf page 50 http://heroicrelics.org/info/s-ii/s-ii-stage-systems-v2-full-download.php  The Saturn V press kit mentions the level sensors in the first stage but only talks about the LH2 ones in detail.  No doubt you can turn up some others.

Great and so nice. Thanks

@OrganicMarble: Thanks, this is an interesting site. It pointed me to "Saturn V Flight Manual SA-503" which is a very nice original source.

Awesome schematics!
