# What's the viscosity of chilled RP-1?

Tags: liquid-fuel, kerosene

I would like to compare the viscosity of "chilled" RP-1 as it is used for Falcon 9 launches to that of some everyday fluids. However, I am unable to find this information elsewhere. Would you please help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How cold do you want it?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Falcon 9 Full Thrust cools it to -7°C

Comment: different but viscosity-related question: [Does the NK-33 engine require subcooled kerosene so cold that it turns to wax?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14456/12102)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this nasaspaceflight.com forum post](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=42302.0), the dynamic viscosity of Falcon 9 chilled RP-1 is about 3.3 [cP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poise_(unit)).

[The table here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/absolute-viscosity-liquids-d_1259.html) lists the viscosities of some maybe-not-so-everyday fluids; Falcon fuel is kept twice as viscous as ordinary kerosene at room temperature (1.64 cP), comparable to milk or blood. Water at room temperature is 0.89 cP.

I tried to find a more authoritative reference for the 3.3 cP figure, but had only partial success. Wikipedia gives the fuel temperature for Falcon as 266.5 K (-6.6º C). [This NIST document](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-C13-18e6f8b04c5baea8df583f63c83ce583/pdf/GOVPUB-C13-18e6f8b04c5baea8df583f63c83ce583.pdf) contains extensive information on RP-1's properties, including its *kinematic* viscosity across a broad range of temperatures -- [kinematic viscosity being the ratio of dynamic viscosity to density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Dynamic_and_kinematic_viscosity). Unfortunately, the density information in the document only goes down to 0º C. The temperature-density relationship is very close to linear over the measured range, however, and if I extrapolate the density down to the target temperature I get 0.819 g/cc. The kinematic viscosity for Falcon juice is about 3.7 mm^2/s, implying a dynamic viscosity of 3.7 * 0.819 = 3.0 cP, which is at least in the ballpark of the unreferenced 3.3 cP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this answer is fine. However I'd prefer a more authoritative source than a forum post ... is there any?

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut Added some more info; no hard reference but 3.3 cP seems at least plausible.

Comment: Thank you for the [rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Dynamic_viscosity) I just got sent down figuring out what the heck a Poise is. Cool answer :)!